# Show single object Properties divided by attributes using custom Objects PropertyDescriptor in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#

I have a problem using custom PropertyDescriptor with objects array.

I have a Class with more Properties with a lot of Attribute like Category and Description.
I want to show list of these properties in a PropertyGrid.
I have written a custom PropertyDescriptor like this:

```
public class CollectionPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor {
  #region Fields
  private object[] objs = null;
  private int index = -1;
  #endregion
  #region PropertyDescriptor

  public ObjectsCollectionPropertyDescriptor(object[] coll, int idx)
     : base("#" + idx.ToString(), null) {
     this.objs = coll;
     this.index = idx;
  }

  public override bool CanResetValue(object component) {
     return false;
  }

  public override string DisplayName {
     get { return string.Format("Item ", index + 1); }
  }

  public override Type ComponentType {
     get { return this.objs.GetType(); }
  }

  public override object GetValue(object component) {
     return this.objs[index]; // Here
  }

  public override bool IsReadOnly {
     get { return true; }
  }

  public override Type PropertyType {
     get { return this.objs[index].GetType(); }
  }

  public override void ResetValue(object component) {
     return;
  }

  public override void SetValue(object component, object value) {
     return;
  }

  public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) {
     return false;
  }
  #endregion
```

}

In PropertyGrid, I see the correct object properties but without order and no Category Attribute division... Why?
I think that the Custom propertyDescriptor does not consider all its Attributes.

How can I show for every object his Properties like in single selection(ex, divided by categories.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have solved my problem, in *CollectionPropertyDescriptor* you must override method to get **TypeConverter** for ONLY object that have his converter in collection like this:

```
public override TypeConverter Converter {
     get {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this.objs[index]);
     }
  }
```

Bye All.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must implement and specify a [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for `Category`. It should allow you to type in a text that is transformed to a `Category` and to display a `Category` as text.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, TypeConverter of CollectionPropertyDescriptor ? Because my single object in collection just contains TC.

Comment: I am thinking of something like this: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/use-a-type-converter-with-a-propertygrid-control-in-c/.